# Any Stack Overflow API for Objective-C available?

Tags: support, api

I'm trying to write a Stack Overflow app for iPhone and iPad. Is there an Objective-C API?

Answer (score 5):

- [CoreStack : An Objective C Library](https://stackapps.com/questions/1194/corestack-an-objective-c-library)

Comment: Thanks Slaks, I think this could be the solution.

Comment: You're welcome.  You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 2):

To be more exact...

https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/objective-c+library